# Search by full release date, not just year

Tags: release

Is there an effective resource to search for a cd by its release date? Being able to just input the exact date would be ideal, but even just a list of albums released for a given month/year would be helpful.

I've found a couple places to search by year only, but that leaves me with way too many results to sift through.

Comment: Related (possibly a duplicate of your post): [Is it somehow possible to get more exact release dates than just the YEARS for CD albums?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/12184/11263)

Answer (score 3):

Rate Your Music has a great feature where you can generate lists of albums based on whatever you want - by label, genre, rating, etc.

And a pretty cool tool for custom charts: http://rateyourmusic.com/customchart - where you can list releases from each decade.

AllMusic has an even more advanced tool where you find album releases per year. The only problem is that they list albums that were re-released: http://www.allmusic.com/advanced-search - still a great tool.

Comment: AllMusic is what I was trying to use initially, but the main problem with that (and with RYM) is the inability to get any more specific than the year. At the very least, having all the albums from a given year displayed but sorted chronologically would be enough to win me over.