# Is it somehow possible to get more exact release dates than just the YEARS for CD albums?

Tags: album, cd, release, database

I'm trying to make a timeline of sorts. Frustratingly, I can only find the **years** when these CDs/albums were released, but I want to know the month and day as well!

Example: https://www.discogs.com/artist/83100-Just-D?type=Releases&subtype=Albums&filter_anv=0

It says just the year when each album was released. Clicking on it for "more info" says nothing about any specific date.

I've hunted around on all kinds of other websites as well. Each "database" of information always seems to lack... any useful data.

This actually surprises me since these, while internationally obscure, are "officially" released CDs sold in physical stores all over Sweden in the 1990s.

Comment: if you cant find any databases with release dates at that level of specificity, you might have to google for promotional statements and reviews of the era on a case-by-case basis. even if they dont give you exact dates, you should be able to narrow it down to a few days.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [Search by full release date, not just year](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/934/11263)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Search by full release date, not just year](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/934/search-by-full-release-date-not-just-year)